# making imagebutton changed when presses

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-button

i want to make image button, so when it pressed i will replase  the not-pressed image to pressed image of the button, and then go to other activity. i have two different images in drawable.

i have two xml files:

first one- load the main activity: background and image button

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:background="@android:color/black"
 android:orientation="vertical" >



<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/b1_l"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/s1"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"  
    android:background="@color/trans"

    android:src="@drawable/b1_l" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

second one:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

   <item android:state_pressed="false"
   android:drawable="@drawable/image_not_pressed" />

   <item android:state_pressed="true"
   android:drawable="@drawable/image_pressed"" />

</selector>
```

what is the code that i need to write in addition to my xml?
or can i pass the xml and write it only as code...?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to usually have drawable for pressed and default(unpressed) state. You can have the xml file like this(below) for that. You need to put this xml file in the drawable folder and then use as src for ImageButton or background source in case of Button.

**Lets name it is mybutton.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true" 
                android:drawable="@drawable/your image name" /> 
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="true" 
                android:drawable="@drawable/your image name" /> 
    <item   android:drawable="@drawable/your image name" /> 
</selector>
```

**You layout file for main activity:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:background="@android:color/black"
 android:orientation="vertical" >



<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/b1_l"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/s1"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"  
    android:background="@color/trans"

    android:src="@drawable/mybutton" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: so if i understant right, there is three states (in your example) of the imagebutton?

as you said, this is a case of imagebutton. so in the xml of the main activity (where the imagebutton is) i need to set the background of the imagebutton to the other xml file?

android:background"@drawable/ ***.xml"  ? 

thank you.

Comment: yes there is one more state called focused. Here in link you can find details about different states possible with selector. But all of them are not associated with button. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList

Comment: In you main activity, the layout file has image button. You need to set the Imagebuttons source to @drawable/<your xml file name>. Btw you do not need to have .xml while referencing it.

Comment: I have modified the answer. If you find it helpful. I suggest you mark it.

Answer (score 0):

You migth want do check out android developer guide on this

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/button.html